# How to remove those "\x00\x00"

Tags: python, string, byte

How to remove those "\x00\x00" in a string ?
I have many of those strings (example shown below). I can use `re.sub` to replace those "\x00". But I am wondering whether there is a better way to do that? Converting between unicode, bytes and string is always confusing.

```
'Hello\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'.
```

Comment: Apart from removing the \x00 from your string, you might want to put some thought into why you have them in the first place. Maybe the code that builds the strings could deal with them?

Comment: The code you wrote that produces this string is probably wrong.

Comment: @Neil, It is because I am a C-wrapper where I should provided max possible length for the string. For those strings which are short, "\x00"s are appended at the end.

Comment: @LuffyCyliu, in the C-wrapper, consider including the actual length of the data when you convert the char array to a Python Object. `strlen` on an array will be faster than a Python str.rstrip or str.replace, and make the Python interface more intuitive. Maybe https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/bytes.html and `PyBytes_FromStringAndSize()` would help.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you are dealing with a zero-padded buffer then you can use `rstrip` to remove trailing `\x00`s

```
>>> text = 'Hello\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> text.rstrip('\x00')
'Hello'
```

It removes all `\x00` characters **at the end** of the string but keeps any nulls in the middle. Not suitable for null-terminated strings that may contain random data after the terminator.

If you are dealing with a *null*-terminated string where the first zero indicates the end of string, but there might be other characters following it, you should use anregen's solution.

```
>>> text = 'Hello\x00\x24\x4e\x32'
>>> text.split('\x00', 1)[0]
'Hello'
```

It splits the text at the first zero and returns the slice. It works with strings having no *null* character too.

*EDIT:*
Explained rstrip in more detail and provided a correct use case.
Included alternative solution.

Comment: this is limiting to just the right of the string. we should have something which can remove from any location in the string.

Answer (score 64):

```
>>> a = 'Hello\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' 
>>> a.replace('\x00','')
'Hello'
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, the question is how to remove a pattern from a string, not from the "end of the string"  like the current accepted answer, or "the end and beginning of the string", etc.

Answer (score 14):

I think the more general solution is to use:

```
cleanstring = nullterminatedstring.split('\x00',1)[0]
```

Which will `split` the string using `\x00` as the delimeter `1` time.  The `split(...)` returns a 2 element list: everything before the null in addition to everything after the null (it removes the delimeter).  Appending `[0]` only returns the portion of the string before the first null (\x00) character, which I believe is what you're looking for.

The convention in some languages, specifically C-like, is that a single null character marks the end of the string.  For example, you should also expect to see strings that look like:

```
'Hello\x00dpiecesofsomeoldstring\x00\x00\x00'
```

The answer supplied here will handle that situation as well as the other examples.

Comment: Great answer, helped me a lot. By the way it might be worth mentioning that in some cases you need to split by b'\x00' instead of '\x00' (if you actually are working with bytes, which in this case could happen)

Answer (score 12):

Building on the answers supplied, I suggest that strip() is more generic than rstrip() for cleaning up a data packet, as strip() removes chars from the beginning and the end of the supplied string, whereas rstrip() simply removes chars from the end of the string.

However, NUL chars are not treated as whitespace by default by strip(), and as such you need to specify explicitly. This can catch you out, as print() will of course not show the NUL chars. My solution that I used was to clean the string using "`.strip().strip('\x00')`":

```
>>> arbBytesFromSocket = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00hello\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> arbBytesAsString = arbBytesFromSocket.decode('ascii')
>>> print(arbBytesAsString)
hello
>>> str(arbBytesAsString)
'\x00\x00\x00\x00hello\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> arbBytesAsString = arbBytesFromSocket.decode('ascii').strip().strip('\x00')
>>> str(arbBytesAsString)
'hello'
>>>
```

This gives you the string/byte array required, without the NUL chars on each end, and also preserves any NUL chars inside the "data packet", which is useful for received byte data that may contain valid NUL chars (eg. a C-type structure). NB. In this case the packet must be "wrapped", i.e. surrounded by non-NUL chars (prefix and suffix), to allow correct detection, and thus only strip unwanted NUL chars.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `strip` and `rstrip` and they didn't work, but this one did;
Use `split` and then `join` the result `list`:

```
if '\x00' in name:
    name=' '.join(name.split('\x00'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Neil wrote, '...you might want to put some thought into why you have them in the first place.'
For my own issue with this error code, this led me to the problem. My saved file that I was reading from was in unicode. Once I re-saved the file as a plain ASCII text, the problem was solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem copy lists out of Excel.  Process was:

- Copy a list of ID numbers sent to me in Excel
- Run set of pyton code that:

  - Read the clipboard as text

  - txt.Split('\n') to give a list

  - Processed each element in the list
    (updating the production system as requird)

Problem was intermitently was returning multiple '\x00' at the end of the text when reading the clipboard.

Have changed from using win32clipboard to using pyperclip to read the clipboard, and it seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30808522)