# Encoding error when trying to open json file from django app

Tags: python, json, django

I have a `json` file in the same directory with my app where I have saved some names and passwords. When a user clicks a button, I am trying to retrieve these data and compare it with the input he gave. However, I get an encoding error 
`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

I tried adding `errors='ignore'` and change encoding without success.

My login function which opens the `json` file:

```
def login(name,password):
    with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
        try:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
            #data = json.load(f) didnt work also
            print(data)

        except ValueError:  # includes simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError
            print('Decoding JSON has failed')
            return False

        f.close()
```

And this is in my django app

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        given_name = request.POST.get('name', None)
        given_password = request.POST.get('pass', None)
        # do something with user
        if login(given_name, given_password):
            about(request)
        else:
            test_home(request)
         ....
```

Json file:

```
{
    "names": [
        "test",
    ],
    "passwords": [
        "test",
    ]
}
```

Comment: This brings up another error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'TextIOWrapper' which doesnt show up if i use json.load(f)

Comment: Your `json` file is probably empty or you are using a wrong path to open it.

Comment: Do you have these weird characters in your 'data.json'? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883476/how-to-remove-those-x00-x00

Comment: It isnt empty and its in the same folder so why would the path cause problems?

Comment: @chaooder no i dont

Comment: sorry, I meant `json.load(f)`, not `json.loads(f)`! see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719689/what-is-the-difference-between-json-load-and-json-loads-functions) ;-)

Comment: @MrFuppes yes i undrestood it but that also didnt work

Comment: looking at your `json` content, there are commas after the strings in "names" / "passwords" lists. `json` therefore expects more list elements... try removing the commas, worked for me.

Comment: @MrFuppes that's exactly the issue.  JSON doesn't tolerate the trailing commas at the end of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try modifying the json file as I pointed out in the comment;

```
{
    "names": [
        "test"
    ],
    "passwords": [
        "test"
    ]
}
```

now you should get

```py
with open(file) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data
Out[5]: {'names': ['test'], 'passwords': ['test']}
```