# Strings are too long

Tags: python, python-3.x

I print a few strings like this:

```
print(name, len(name), type(name))
```

which outputs

```
Norway 32 <class 'str'>
Denmark 32 <class 'str'>
France 32 <class 'str'>
East Timor 32 <class 'str'>
South Africa 32 <class 'str'>
Lesotho 32 <class 'str'>
Mexico 32 <class 'str'>
Uruguay 32 <class 'str'>
Brazil 32 <class 'str'>
Bolivia 32 <class 'str'>
Peru 32 <class 'str'>
Colombia 32 <class 'str'>
```

These strings clearly don't have a length of 32. However, they come from a data source with a maximum string length of 32.

A simple comparison like this always fails:

```
if name == "Mexico":
```

`strip()`ping did not work either.

What is going on? Why are these strings longer than they actually are? How can I compare them to a string like *Mexico*?

Comment: They might have trailing null bytes, for example. Try `print(yourString.encode())`.

Comment: also try `print(repr(name))`, and please show the input data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove those "\x00\x00"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883476/how-to-remove-those-x00-x00)

Comment: That's all been very helpful. 'encode' and 'repr' let me see those pesky '\x00'. And the question about how to remove them too. So maybe this is just a duplicate?