# Putting decoded bytes in dict changes back to original?

Tags: python, byte, ascii, python-3.8

I am trying to decode some bytes to ASCII, but when decoding to ASCII and putting it in a dict, it changes back to the bytes format (?)

```py
b = b'Hello\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

print(b.decode('ascii')) # Hello
converted = b.decode('ascii')
print(converted, type(converted))  # Hello <class 'str'>

test_dict = {}
test_dict["converted"] = converted
print(test_dict) # {'converted': 'Helloo\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'} ???
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: As you can tell, `converted` is a string. It also happens to include some trailing null characters. What you are seeing is just the way python represents a string with null characters in it. Notice how the string no longer has a 'b' in front.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, do you know a way to get rid of those null chacaters, without like hacky regex?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try: `b.decode('ascii').strip()`

Comment: What do you think the result should be instead? Why? According to what logic? Why do you have this `bytes` data in the first place; why do you expect it to represent text at all; and why does it have many trailing null bytes? It is only possible to do *anything* "without hacky" code, by *clearly understanding the problem that is being solved* and *properly modelling it*. Hacky code results from just doing whatever gets the right answer - that's what "hack" *means*.

Comment: Checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883476/how-to-remove-those-x00-x00) on how to remove trailing null characters from a string.

Comment: For example, if the data comes from a C-like interface, and the first `\x00` byte is intended to represent the end of the data (which the other language is feebly pretending is already "a string"), then it would make more sense to search for that byte and slice the data there *before* attempting any string conversion. After all, by those definitions, if there are non-zero bytes after that point they should be ignored, right?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel When decoding to ASCII I expect it to remove those null characters. I have these null characters because I am reading a `.img` that has info about filenames and files. To parse these filenames I need to get around these null characters.

Comment: Then the next step is to make sure you understand the `.img` format at that level of detail. Are the byte sequences a specific length? Is there a length count somewhere of the meaningful data? Is there a reason the null characters can't be intended actual characters of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to remove the [null character `\x00`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), use `replace`:

```py
converted = b.decode('ascii').replace("\x00", "")
```

With your dictionary code, you get:

```py
{'converted': 'Hello'}
```